# store different post variables in a session array

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to store a different  value in to a session variable in php for
example I have a post variable called `$_POST['sit']` which takes different values every time the user submits a form , I want to store all the different values that the post variable will take until the user stop submitting the form , how can I store all the different values of the post variable in to a session variable array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to start the session, check for the existence of the post variable, and then push into an array stack within the session. here's psuedo-code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['sit'])){
    $_SESSION['sits'][] = $_POST['sit'];
}
```

Now when you `var_dump($_SESSION['sits'])` it will hold reference to all of the posted values from `$_POST['sit']`